# ruby on Rails-login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a simple login_app using 'Authlogic' gem and i got this error:

```
NameError in UsersController#create
undefined local variable or method `users' for #<UsersController:0x0000000354ba48>

Extracted source (around line #28):
```

code:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params users ) # <- this line
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
```

Rails.root: `/home/ameex/projects/login_app`

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

please help me to resolve this

Comment: Are you using `Rails4`? then it is supposed to something like this `@user = User.new(users_params )`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **`Rails4`**,this should work.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:your_user_attr1,:your_user_attr2,..)
  end
end
```

Have a look at **`Strong Parameters`** in these **[Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)**.

Answer (score 1):

To back up `Pavan`'s answer, the error you had was this:

> UsersController#create undefined local variable or method `users' for
>   #

This is a typical problem, and basically means you've referenced a local object which doesn't exist (in your case `users`). The issue is that now you're trying to call this, Rails cannot find it, leading to the exception

--

**Params**

As `Pavan` pointed out, the problem you have is you're calling:

```
@user = User.create(params users)
```

The problem here is you're calling a non-existent object, as explained; but what is much more important is your actual syntax is wrong. You're getting confused with two variables inside Rails:

> - [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) hash
> - [`strong_params`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) method

When you create a new object in `Rails 4`, you need to tell [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller) which params values you wish to populate the new record with. This is currently done by using `strong_params`, which essentially whitelists different members of the `params` hash

The bottom line is when you reference data / objects in Rails, you have to have them available beforehand. Your referencing of `params users` references neither the relevant `params[:key][:value]`, nor your `strong_params` method

Hopefully this gives you some more ideas

Comment: Your Explanation is quite awesome.Probably a better answer than mine.My answer lacks that explanation.